# Set Mist Pass Distance

Tags: camera, render-passes

I wanted to use the Mist Pass for the first time today. I have a scene [1 BE = 1 MM] which is pretty large, and I won't change the scale of single objects for the individual shaders are specified to that scale.

However, if I activate the checkbox in the camera tab to show the range (distance) of the Mist Pass, the little X-marker doesn't even exit the camera itself, thus the Mist Pass is a completely white image when rendering.

How and where can I set the distance of the Mist Pass? I didn't find any setting to change it, actually.

Thanks beforehand for your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Mist Pass" is the properites windows under the world tab.

[image]

Comment: And only visible after **Mist** has been enabled in the **View Layer Properties** tab under **Passes**. This is probably the first thing most people will do, but it's worth mentioning that it's a prerequisite.